# Cloud Functions for Firebase suddenly timing out

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Suddenly after deploying my functions today some of our functions suddenly always timeout. I see this in the cloud functions console. This seems to happen when nesting and returning promises. Strange thing is this never happened before.

Here's my code.

```
exports.pushMessageQueue = functions.database.ref('/userPushMessagesQueue/{userId}/{messageId}').onWrite(event => {
    if (!event.data.exists()) {
        console.log('DOES NOT EXIST!');
        return "not exists";
    }

    console.log("EXISTS!");

    const userId = event.params['userId'];
    const messageId = event.params['messageId'];

    const payload = event.data.val();

    return database.ref('devices').orderByChild('user_id').equalTo(userId).once('value', snapshot => {
        if (!snapshot.exists()) {
            return "no devices found";
        }

        const devices = snapshot.val();

        const deviceTokens = [];

        snapshot.forEach(deviceSnap => {
            const device = deviceSnap.val();
            deviceTokens.push(device['fcm_key']);
        });

        const removeFromQueue = database.ref(`/userPushMessagesQueue/${userId}/${messageId}`);

        console.log('then0');

        return removeFromQueue.set(null).then(() => {
            console.log('then1');
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceTokens, payload).then(() => {
                console.log('then2');
                return "send";
            });
        }, (error) => {
            console.log('error1!');
            console.log(error);
        });
    });
});
```

In the console then0 is logged, not then1 and then2. And that while I receive the push notification and the entry is removed from the queue.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Since today I've experienced similar problems with my Firebase cloud functions. Is there any fix available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning the once() function, not a promise chain.

Essentially, you've written this:

```
//returns the once promise
return ref.once('value', function(snap) { 
  /* some stuff that doesn't affect the promise chain happens here */
});
```

When what you wanted is this:

```
// returns whatever happens in the .then() callback
return ref.once('value').then(snap => {
   /* now whatever you return here affects the promise chain */
});
```